C#: 404 error when downloading an asset from GitHub
I wanted to tell you about the problem I encountered trying to download a release file (https://github.com/OWNER/REPO/releases/download/TAG/FILE) from a private GitHub repository.
When I try to download the file I get the error:

Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).

Used packages:
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;                                   
using System.IO;                                              
using System.Net.Http;                                        
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

Code:
string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
using HttpClient client = new();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Add(new ProductInfoHeaderValue("Pippo", "2.3"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("token", V.token);
try
{
    string releaseUrl = $"https://api.github.com/repos/{V.owner}/{V.repoName}/releases/latest";
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(releaseUrl);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    string jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    JObject release = JObject.Parse(jsonResponse);
    MessageBox.Show($"Release: {release["name"]}");
    var assets = release["assets"];
    foreach (var asset in assets)
    {
        string assetName = asset["name"].ToString();
        string downloadUrl = asset["browser_download_url"].ToString();
        MessageBox.Show($"Downloading: {assetName}");
        string filePath = Path.Combine(desktopPath, assetName);
        using HttpResponseMessage assetResponse = await client.GetAsync(downloadUrl);
        assetResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        byte[] fileBytes = await assetResponse.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
        await File.WriteAllBytesAsync(filePath, fileBytes);
        MessageBox.Show($"Downloaded: {assetName} in {filePath}");
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show($"Error: {ex.Message}");
}

I am sure the token is right because it shows me MessageBox, which is only possible with authentication.
I tried downloading another file from a different reposity, this time a public one, and.... I succeeded.
I could not find any solution, and since I have seen many with the same problem, I opened this thread.
I thank anyone who can give me a hand!

I am sure the token is right because it shows me MessageBox, which is only possible with authentication. That is not true. Authentication is only going to be used once you initiate the web request. It validates authentication on HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(releaseUrl); not before the try.
